# assign a hex value to float returns a wrong value

Tags: c, hex

I'm new to C and I tried following:

```
float f = 0x41933333;
```

this should give me the float number: `18.4` but when I look into the memory I find the hex value:

```
66 26 83 4e
```

which is as float: `41933333.0000`

Why is my hex value interpreted as a decimal number?

Comment: Are you really sure with the number you are quoting as your results? As `float f = 0x41933333;` shall give `1.10016589e+09`for `f`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alternatively, you can perform a casting by interpreting the value of an int as float

```
unsigned int n = 0x41933333;
float f = *((float*)&n);
```

Comment: This only works if the size of an `int` is the same as the size of a `float`.

Comment: This methods violates C’s aliasing rules (C 2018 6.5 7) and is unnecessary because an interpretation of desired bits as a floating-point object can be performed properly using `memcpy` (in C or C++) or a union (in C).

Answer (score 3):

`0x41933333` is an integer constant.  When assigned to a `float`, the integer is converted.  If you need a hexadecimal floating point constant, you have to use that notation explicitly:

```
0x0.933333P4
```

or something vaguely similar — I've only made a casual guess at what the correct value is, but the `0x` prefix and the `P` exponent are crucial parts of a hexadecimal floating point constant.  See section 6.4.4.2 Floating constants in ISO/IEC 9899:2011 for the full details.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to plug in the raw value directly, use a union.